# num_rows through 2 tables in a mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know if it is possible to do a query in which two different tables will be checked and as a result the number of rows will return or even true/false.

The reason is that I have a function:

```
function exists($email){
    global $db;
    $query = $db->query("SELECT Email FROM table1, table2 WHERE Email= '$email' ");
    $check = $query->num_rows;
    return ($check == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

I know that this only works if the tables have the same structure. In my case it is not like that.

Both tables just have the field "email" in common but nothing else.

table1 is like:

field_1 | field_2 | field_3 | field_4 | field_5 | **field_6 (Email)**| field_7 | field_8 | field_9

table2 is like:

field_1 | field_2 | field_3 | field_4 |.... | **field_17 (Email)**| field_18 | field_19 | field_20

So I would like to know if this is possible? I looked through JOIN but didn't get it what to do with that?

Comment: mysql fiddle, build a setup with your current tables so it's clear to us what your structure is.

Comment: Or provide an example so its less confused as to what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

Try below:

```
SELECT SUM(cnt) as total_count
(
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM table1  WHERE Email= '$email' 
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM table1  WHERE Email= '$email' 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use UNION:

```
SELECT email
FROM   table1
UNION
SELECT email
FROM   table2
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use unions, like `SELECT email FROM table1 where Email = '$email' union SELECT email FROM table2 where Email = '$email'`.

You have to remember that selected column count must be the same for both queries.

Also, fetching rows when you in fact don't need them is a waste of resources - just get count of matching rows directly from the database.

Comment: hello, what does that mean that the selected column count must be the same? i updated my question. thanks.

Comment: It means that field count after ``select`` keyword must me the same, eg. ``select foo from table1 union select bar from table2`` will work, but ``select foo, baz from table1 union select bar from table2`` won't.